# Insert Cut Cells and Paste Special Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy just the values of my pivot table into a sheet.  I am trying to create a template, so the size of the pivot table will vary and I have more to the spreadsheet under where these values need to be pasted.

I have figured out how to either (a) insert cut cells via macro or (b) paste special (values), but I cannot figure out how to paste special (values) and insert (i.e. create additional rows).

I am currently using a simple:

```
    Sub CutPasteGainLossSales()
        Range("D3").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SchA").Select
        Range("B12").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
             :=False, Transpose:=False
    End Sub
```

OR

```
    Sub testcutpastespecialinsert()

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Principal Amounts Received").PivotSelect "", _
             xlDataAndLabel, True
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SchA").Select
        Range("B5").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End Sub
```

Is there some way to combine these two?  Or is there an alternative altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can't cut and paste values so you could clear the original cells if you didn't want them. I think this is one of those rare occasions where Select is impossible to avoid (a sure invitation for me to be proved wrong...)

```
Sub testcutpastespecialinsert()

Dim p As PivotTable

Set p = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Principal Amounts Received")
p.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy

With Sheets("SchA").Range("B5")
    .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

'these two lines clear the original table
p.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it inserted the cut pivot table and then pasted the cell values below it.  Thus, the insert cut cells worked and didn't overwrite my text, but the pasted cells below that did.

I'm wondering if perhaps the solution is to somehow get the dimensions of the pivot table (number of rows) and insert that many rows into the destination sheet and then paste the special values.

Answer (score 0):

So, I seem to have solved my own issue.  I used some of the @SJR 's code and then went a different way with it (see issue with that code above).   My solution was to: copy the pivot table I needed from one worksheet, insert that into the summary page (which pushed down any data beneath where I needed this inserted), clear that insertion (which retains the space provided by the insert), then copy the other pivot table again and paste it into the space provided by the original copy/insert cut cells.

```
Sub cutpastespecialinsert()

Dim p As PivotTable

Set p = Sheets("SchAPivots").PivotTables("Principal Amounts Received")
p.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy

With Sheets("SchA").Range("B6")
    .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("SchA").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(ActiveCell.PivotTable.Name).PivotSelect "", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Clear
End With

Sheets("SchAPivots").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Principal Amounts Received").PivotSelect "", _
    xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy
Sheets("SchA").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I am also currently working on a way to do this by counting the rows in a pivot table and then inserting that number of rows.